# How Golden Calf massacre can be reconciled with the Halachah

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, capital-punishment, golden-calf-egel

In Moses' words, God ordered a massacre in a very specific way: infidels should be executed with swords, and one should target his own relatives first:

> ".וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם כֹּה־אָמַר ה' אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל:
> שִׂימוּ אִישׁ־חַרְבּוֹ עַל־יְרֵכוֹ
> עִבְרוּ וָשׁוּבוּ מִשַּׁעַר לָשַׁעַר בַּמַּחֲנֶה
> וְהִרְגוּ אִישׁ־אֶת־אָחִיו וְאִישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵהוּ וְאִישׁ אֶת־קְרֹבוֹ׃"
> .
> "He said to them, “Thus says the LORD, the God of Israel:
> a. Each of you put a sword on thigh,
> b. go back and forth from gate to gate throughout the camp,
> c. and slay brother, neighbor, and kin.” [Exodus.32.27](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he)

Those orders contradict the established Halacha in all three aspects:

1. Idolaters must be brought before a court to be judged, there was no rush to kill them on the spot.
2. Idolaters are executed through Skilah, not sword, as in Mishna Sanhedrin 7.4 "אלו הן הנסקלין:... והעובד עבודה זרה,"
3. The victims are executed by their witnesses, who can not be relatives, esp. brothers.

It might be said that the event occurred prior to the giving of the laws, but the orders came straight from God and should be consistent with the Halachah.

How do God's orders for the massacre reconcile with the existing Halacha?

Comment: How could Eliyahu offer sacrifices on Har Carmel?

Comment: Aren’t the inhabitants of an ir hanidachat put to the sword?

Comment: An explicit command from Hashem **is** Halachah and overrides anything else. Those people were condemned by the *highest possible court*.

Comment: @sabbahillel Oh, that's the famous Euthyphro dilemma: is God subject to his own laws. Anyway, please elaborate on the reasons to stray from mainstream law.

Comment: 'elaborate on the reasons to stray from mainstream law' is a new and separate question from the one you asked. You didn't ask why did God decide it should be so in this case. You instead asked how it fits and is reconciled with the general halacha. If you want to know why God decided to do it this way in this case, you may want to rephrase your question.

Comment: @JoelK's comment is exactly it. See Rashi to 32:20.

Comment: file under "why do bad things happen to good people"

Comment: As per @JoelK, the whole of *klal yisrael* had a *din* of an *ir ha'nidachas*.

Answer (score 0):

Rashi explains that those who had sinned in front of witnesses were killed by the sword upon the decree of Hashem. We see that Hashem did not bring them in front of the bais din as the entire congregation of Israel were not in a position to actually serve as a court. Instead He brought them in front of the *bais din shel shamaim* and decreed the punishment upon them as the Creator and Master of the Universe. An example could be like the punishment decreed upon the people of S'dom. That is Hashem decrees the punishment that is worthy of being done. In this case, those who would follow Hashem were being tested to determine if they were able to carry out the decree of Hashem. Verse 25 shows that the people could not bring themselves to act even if they had not succumbed to the sin. That is why Moshe had to call upon them to take their swords and rally to the service of Hashem in verse 26.

See Rav Hirsch in his commentary on verse 25 and 26.

[Ki Sisa 32:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893/showrashi/true#v20)

> Then he took the calf they had made, burned it in fire, ground it to
> fine powder, scattered [it] upon the surface of the water, and gave
> [it to] the children of Israel to drink.

**RASHI**

> **and gave [it to] the children of Israel to drink:** He intended to test them like women suspected of adultery [are tested, as prescribed
> in Num. 5:11-31] (A.Z. 44a). Three [different] death penalties were
> meted out there: (1) If there were witnesses [to the worship] and
> warning [had been issued to the sinners, they were punished] by the
> sword, according to the law (Deut. 13:13-18) that applies to the
> people of a city that has been led astray who are many [people
> involved]. (2) [Those who practiced idolatry with] witnesses but
> without warning [died] from a plague, as it is said: “Then the Lord
> struck the people with a plague” (verse 35). (3) [Those who practiced
> idolatry both] without witnesses and without warning [died] from
> dropsy, for the water tested them and their stomachs swelled up (Yoma
> 66b).